# In Java how to read the latest string of constantly generated stream fast?

Tags: java, stream, real-time

In Java I have a process constantly generating output. Of course it's placed into some buffer of the out `stream` (FiFo) until it's processed. But what I need is sometimes read the latest, actual `string` of the stream as if it was LiFo. The problem is when I need it, I have to read all the previous output generated between my reads, because streams don't have random access - which is very slow.

I use `BufferedReader(StreamReader(process.getInputStream()))`

The buffer of `BufferedReader` also poses a little problem.
**How can I discard all the output I don't need, fast?**
If possible I wouldn't like to create separate reader-discarder thread.

I tried:

```
stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
      InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 1000);
```

then when I need to read the Output:

```
            stdInput.skip(iS.available() + 1000); //get the generated up
            //till now sequence length and discard it
            stdInput.readLine(); //to 'flush' the BufferedReader buffer
            s = stdInput.readLine(); //to read the latest string
```

this way is very slow and takes undetermined time

Comment: You'll have to be clearer.  Provide some relevant code, and then show what you have tried so far to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the full code, it may be useful for you to try a few things and see what performs best.  Overall, I'm not sure how much improvement you will see.

1. Remove *BufferedReader* wrapper and benchmark.  It **seems** that your InputStream is memory backed.  Hence reads maybe cheap.  If it is then buffered reader may slow you down.  If reads are expensive, then you should keep it.
2. Try [Channels.newChannel(InputStream in)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel(java.io.InputStream)) and use [ReadableByteChannel.read(ByteBUffer dst)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html) and benchmark.  Again, it depends on your InputStream, but a Channel may show performance benefits.

Overall I'd recommend going the multithreaded approach with an *ExecutorService* and *Callable* class doing the reading and processing into a memory buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It turned out I could just launch the process each time and get the first output.
It must be quite costly, but suffices for my modest needs.)
The asynchronous channel approach is interesting and would be the one I'd try, should it be too costly.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (I don't know your implementation): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark(int)

BufferedReader has a mark method:

```
public void mark(int readAheadLimit)
          throws IOException
```

> Marks the present position in the stream. Subsequent calls to reset()
>   will attempt to reposition the stream to this point.

If you know the size of your data and you can utilize that size to set the position to the part of the stream in which you care about.

Comment: I don't think it's what I need: when you mark sth, you can later return to the specified position, which is earlier in the stream (that is fifo sequence). What I need is the latest characters of the stream. Life would be easier if stream was lifo.